# Mongoid Create Embedded Document Inside Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, embedding, database-relations

I have two models **User** and **Status**.
Status is embedded in User:

**User.rb**

```
class User

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :status, as: :statusable
```

**Status.rb**

```
class Status

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :statusable, polymorphic: true
```

Now I'm trying to create the status Document Inside user:

```
* User.create!(:name =>'try',:status => {:num => '111'})
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Statu
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in 'block in constantize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in 'each'
    ....
    ....

* u = User.create!(:name =>'try')
u.status = Status.create!(:num => '222')
=> Mongoid::Errors::NoParent: 
Problem:
  Cannot persist embedded document Status without a parent document.
Summary:
  If the document is embedded, in order to be persisted it must always have a reference to its parent document. This is most likely caused by either calling Status.create or Status.create! without setting the parent document as an attribute.
Resolution:
  Ensure that you have set the parent relation if instantiating the embedded document direcly, or always create new embedded documents via the parent relation.

* u.status = {:num => '222'}
=> NameError: uninitialized constant Statu
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation:

> Model class name cannot end with "s", because it will be considered as
>   the pluralized form of the word. For example Status would be
>   considered as the plural form of Statu, which will cause a few known
>   problems.

So try to define your relation with the `class_name` metadata forcing mongoid to use that Class.

```
embeds_one :status, as: :statusable, class_name: "Status"
```

Comment: Interesting! in mongomapper I have not such problem with `Status` model!

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of issues here.
As answered by marquez, the model class name ending in "s" is problematic but addressable via the class_name specifier.
If you didn't need polymorphism, then you would just use auto generated methods for User#status and User#status=.
But with polymorphism and the class_name override, the "as:" specifier didn't work for me, but the following did.
Hope that this helps you move on.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :statusable, class_name: "Status"
end
```

app/models/status.rb

```
class Status
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :statusable, polymorphic: true
end
```

test/unit/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
  end

  test "basic embedding" do
    User.create!(:name =>'try',:statusable => {:num => '111'})
    assert_equal 1, User.count
    u = User.create!(:name =>'try')
    u.statusable = Status.new(:num => '222')
    assert_equal 2, User.count
    puts
    pp (User.all.to_a.collect{|user| user.serializable_hash})
  end
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/1] UserTest#test_basic_embedding
[{"_id"=>"5277f5077f11bac4b4000001",
  "created_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00,
  "name"=>"try",
  "statusable"=>
   {"_id"=>"5277f5077f11bac4b4000002",
    "created_at"=>nil,
    "num"=>"111",
    "updated_at"=>nil},
  "updated_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00},
 {"_id"=>"5277f5077f11bac4b4000003",
  "created_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00,
  "name"=>"try",
  "statusable"=>
   {"_id"=>"5277f5077f11bac4b4000004",
    "created_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00,
    "num"=>"222",
    "updated_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00},
  "updated_at"=>Mon, 04 Nov 2013 19:27:03 UTC +00:00}]
Finished tests in 0.044048s, 22.7025 tests/s, 45.4050 assertions/s.
1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: The "as:" specifier does work for me, also with polymorphism and the class_name override. Notice that in User record should be a status obj, not a statusable obj. Calling: `s = user.status` and then `s.statusable`, gives the user